# Avoid Package re-upload to PyPI

Tags: python, github, pypi, python-packaging

Do I need to re-upload my package at PyPI when I have already pushed the latest version at GitHub?
Can't they just sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to upload it to PyPI, but you can use Github Actions to help you sync it when you push the newer version.
I think [this](https://packaging.python.org/guides/publishing-package-distribution-releases-using-github-actions-ci-cd-workflows/) and [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/introduction-to-github-actions) may help you, and if you just want an example, you can check [this](https://github.com/SiriusKoan/RandomUsers/blob/main/.github/workflows/python-publish.yml) out.

Comment: Can you please share any reference links? (How to achieve this.)

Comment: OK, I append some references to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Github actions to sync when you publish the newer version.
You can also go to [this](https://github.com/features/actions) to know more about GitHub actions